# BasicNamesValuesPaire not working

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I need to pass variable from android to php.
my file is on localhost, and the connection between android and the file is ok except the php dont get the variables i send from android.
I tried with $_get, $_POST
I tried to add .tostring method after my int variable
doesn't work

Java

```
protected String doInBackground(String... param) {

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p1", param[0].toString()));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p2", param[1].toString()));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p3", param[2].toString()));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p4", param[3].toString()));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p5", param[4].toString()));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", param[6].toString()));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sexe", param[5]));

    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/AppBdd.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            client.execute(httppost);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

My php file appBdd.php :

```
require_once ("rees.php");

$pdo = PdoGsb::getPdoGsb();
$sexe = $_REQUEST['sexe'];
$age = $_REQUEST['age'];
$max  = $_REQUEST['p1'];
$max2  = $_REQUEST['p2'];
$max3  = $_REQUEST['p3'];
$max4  = $_REQUEST['p4'];
$max5  = $_REQUEST['p5'];

$pdo->setClient($sexe, $age, $max, $max2, $max3, $max4, $max5);
```

Comment: `my file is on localhost`. What do you mean with `my file`? And with localhost? You know that every pc or android device is its own localhost?

Comment: i mean im connecting android with my php file on my pc localhost

Comment: Android? Android is an operating system. Please explain your setup to the point first.

Comment: By android i shortcut android studio.
The java code is write in android studio and i'm trying to connect to localhost/appBdd.php on my computer.

Comment: Unbelievable that you do not tell what you are doing. Who is connecting? From where? Tell what you do. How could we know if you do nof tell?

Comment: I use android studio to write java code i send 5 variable to my  doInBackground method wich is supposed to send the variables to my php file located in localhost/... on my computer.
connecting android studio to my php file
dont know how i can be more explicit..

Comment: `connecting android studio to my php file`. Complete nonsense. With Android Studio you will compile an Android app. Your app will try to connect with your web server. Your webserver will forward the request to php interpreter. You did not tell where your Android app is running.

Comment: Well cant tell then...
im just compiling my code into an app in visual studio, so my app is running in an emulator.
Dont know if that's what you expected thanks anyway, will try to find the solution

Comment: Yes that i wanted to know. So your app is running in an emulator. Not on an Android phone or tablet. And your server with php is running on the same computer as the emulator? Not on a different computer? That is your setup. That took a day to find out! So now that we know we could begin debugging. But if you want to do it your self...

Comment: No need to be disrespectful... supposed to be a help and learn site. no point to argue against me to look like the smart guy and just not helping.
You can be nice it would be cool too.